# Alternate Use to 'return' in Scala?

Tags: scala, coding-style

I am working on the Scala Coursera course right now (so I am still very new to the language and the paradigm).

In any case, I have completed the first lesson, but, when I run styleCheck against the code (which is also run as part of the grade), I receive warnings back that I should avoid using return. However, when I don't use return, my if statements just fall through. Here is an example of the code (no hints, per Coursera's honor policy):

```
  if(value == 0) return 1
  if(value == 1) return 0
  if(some.other.value.is.something) return 0

  recursiveCall(some, stuff)
```

Based on my understanding of the problem, I don't believe I can turn these into if/else's (I did try that, and then my solution wasn't correct). So, I'm stuck as to what possible options there may be. I'm also not understanding why I shouldn't use returns in the first place. Explanations/help on both would be much appreciated.

Comment: I can see why someone may have downvoted, but for me the sort of refactor described here was learned behavior (as a Java refugee).

Comment: @som-snytt - You're exactly right. I am coming from a purely imperative world (one I have been in for some time). I am learning Scala particularly for the fact that I know I am going to run across things like this that challenge basic understanding of how I write software. I do wish the person who had downvoted had explained. I don't understand why this question would get a downvote in the first place. I appreciate your response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `return` keyword exists in Scala, but you rarely need it.

The return value of a method in Scala is simply the value of the last expression in the method; you can leave out the `return` keyword.

Note that in Scala, `if` is an *expression*  and not a *statement* - it evaluates to a value. For example, you can assign the result of an `if` expression to a variable:

```
val result = if (x == 3) 5 else 7
```

You could rewrite your code like this:

```
if (value == 0) 1
else if (value == 1) 0
else if (some.other.value.is.something) 0
else recursiveCall(some, stuff)
```

(assuming that `recursiveCall(some, stuff)` also returns a value).

Comment: There ought to be a community wiki about this somewhere.  My comment was not to fear abusing the match, and also not fear refactoring to local defs for ease of reading.

Comment: This is it exactly - I didn't have my recursive call with the final else because I was thinking of "if" being a statement rather than being an expression. Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is about the recursion.

One sees this often:

```
def f(x: X, value: Value): Int = {
  def loop(x: X): Int = ???  // some recursive algorithm
  value match {
    case 0 => 1     // some guard conditions
    case 1 => 0
    case _ if some.condition => 0
    case _ => loop(x)
  }
}
```

That is, some local defs are followed by a small snippet that constitutes the small body of the function.

In particular, a local def is the recursive function to invoke.